# Reduce weight of a electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I have one switch code to identify the windows arch: ia32 and x64, and by this i have two pepflashplayer.dll in my app folder but the weight of the two files is 45.8mb (And the final weight of the app is 74mb), and i think that my app weigh too much for only charging a game in a website

Doesn't exist any method to make the files lighter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the size of my finished app is around 50mb and if your adding 45mb to the package is going to get quite big.

Here's a [github issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2003) on it.

The comment I'm emphasizing is:

> That's the expected size, there is no way to make it smaller.

The reason why it's so big is because electron is loading most of chromium inside that 50mb file which I think it's pretty darn small for 50mb

So no unfortunately there is no way to make it smaller sorry.

Comment: No, that isn't normal, but like I said in my answer: The base size for any Electron app is 50mb, and anything else you package with it adds to the size. So If you had 120mb worth of files in your app then your packaged app would be 170mb in size.

Comment: My code is only a few JS files, but I've seen many people is complaining about this with sizes > 100MB so maybe it is the normal size now. Too bad.

Comment: Yes me too. Although my app is still 50mb so it might be something wrong with the way you're packaging it. From here I would suggest opening a issue on [electron-packager's github repo](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/new/choose).